# Automatic error highlighting for Haxe

Tags: haxe

Is there any tool or IDE for the Haxe programming language that can automatically highlight errors that are detected in Haxe source code, like the Eclipse IDE's automatic Java error highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a pick from here: http://haxe.org/com/ide

As EzeQL said, FlashDevelop is the best option. However it doesn't run outside Windows.

Not on the list, but also worth pointing out is the MonoDevelop [plugin](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/41).

Comment: Do any of these editors actually support automatic error highlighting for Haxe? This feature would be extremely useful, if it existed.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: FlashDevelop definitely does. As for the rest, I don't really know.

Comment: Is there any way to enable live error highlighting in FlashDevelop? I started editing a Haxe file and wrote some non-valid code, but the errors were not automatically highlighted as I was typing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any doing something like that. If you like working with an IDE, the most Complete option is Flashdevelop IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The [Haxe extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nadako.vshaxe) supports this via [diagnostics](https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe/wiki/Diagnostics). By default, they are updated on save, but if you enable the auto save feature, they will update automatically.

```json
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
```

[image]